# awk getline without advancing the file

Tags: awk, getline

I have a file with sections like:

```
requests:
  cpu: X
  memory: 500Mi
limits:
  cpu: Y
  memory: 1Gi
```

When I find `requests:\n  cpu: X` I want to compare it with `limits:\n  cpu: Y`.  Depending on the value of Y, I want to edit X.  So when I reach `cpu: X` I want to scan forward a couple of lines to see what the value of `cpu: Y` is, but then return to the original place in the file so that I can print `cpu: X_2` (where `X_2` is the modified value) and the remaining lines.

If I use `getline`, the position in the file will be advanced.  I could save everything to a buffer as I read with getline and print the whole buffer, but I'm hoping there's a way to either use getline without advancing the position in the file, or to reset the position.

Sample code:

```
awk '
        /requests:/ {
                print $0
                
                # search next 2 lines for cpu
                for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
                        getline
                        ### Something to check the value of limits' cpu needs to go here
                        if ($0 ~ /cpu:/) {
                                print gensub(/cpu: .*/, "cpu: X_2", "g", $0)
                        }
                        else {
                                print $0
                                break
                        }
                }
                next
        }
        
        { print $0 }
'
```

Adding expected output:

Just for instance, say I want requests' cpu to be no more than half of limits' cpu.  The file is a valid yaml file, and everything else in the file needs to remaining unmodified. The A, B, C, etc. below are for illustration of possible file contents that should not be modified.

**INPUT:**

```
A: 1
B: 2
  b1: 1b
  b2: 2b
C: 3
  requests:
    cpu: 200m
    memory: 500Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 300m
    memory: 1Gi
D: 
  - d1a: 1da
    d1b: 1db
  - d2a: 2da
    d2b: 2db
E: 5
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 500Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 1Gi
F:
  f1: 1f
  f2: 2f
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
A: 1
B: 2
  b1: 1b
  b2: 2b
C: 3
  requests:
    cpu: 150m
    memory: 500Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 300m
    memory: 1Gi
D: 
  - d1a: 1da
    d1b: 1db
  - d2a: 2da
    d2b: 2db
E: 5
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 500Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 1Gi
F:
  f1: 1f
  f2: 2f
```

In this case, the first instance of cpu: 200m was reduced to cpu: 150m since 200 was greater than half of 300.  The second instance of cpu with 100m was not modified since it was already less than half of 500m.

Comment: You should better use `yq` for this.

Comment: Using `getline` is rarely the right approach (see awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) and it's not the right approach for your problem. Please [edit] your question to show the exact expected output so we can help you.

Comment: I'm not opposed to a different tool than awk.  I haven't used yq before.

Comment: @RustyLemur, could you please do let us know if you could install yq or not in your system if not then we could come up with other tools(which usually experts don't recommend since yq is specifically designed for these kind of tasks).

Comment: Yes, yq is a candidate for my use.

Answer (score 1):

easier with double processing the file and caching the cpu values to refer in the second round.

```
$ awk 'function min(x,y) {return x<y?x:y} 
       FNR==1{c=0} 
       NR==FNR && /cpu:/ {sub("m","",$2); cpu[++c]=$2; next} 
       /cpu:/            {c++; 
                          if(c%2) 
                            {t=$2; 
                             sub("m","",t); 
                             v=int(min(cpu[c+1]/2,t)); 
                             sub($2,v"m")}}1' file{,}
```